# How to compute the projection of a vector on a plane

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Can someone check whether my work is correct or not?

> Compute the projection of $(1,1,1)$ onto the plane that passes through the points $(1,0,-1), (3,7,-3), (-2,-1,2)$.

**My attempt:** Let $u = (1,1,1)$. I first try to find a vector normal to the plane given by the three points. By  computing a cross product, I got $n = (19,0,19) = (1,0,1)$.

The projection of $u$ onto the plane is  $$\frac{u.n}{||n||^2}u.$$ Is that correct?

Comment: Your normal is correct, but $\frac{\vec{u} \dot{} \vec{n}}{\vec{n} \dot{} \vec{n}}$ is just a scaler. What you want is subtract the perpendicular part to the plane from $\vec{u}$.

Comment: can you please write down the formula? thanks

Comment: Are you familiar with Gram-Schmidt projection?

Comment: no, this is the first time i am seeing the name

Comment: You should be able to express $\vec{u}$ as some point on the plane, plus some amount times two independent vectors, which lie in that plane (this should be the projection) plus some amount times $\vec{n}$. How much do you know of linear algebra.

Answer (score 1):

A plane is of the form $a_1 x_1 + a_2 x_2 + a_3 x_3 = b$. Since we are given three points on the plane, we obtain a system of $3$ linear equations in $a_1, a_2, a_3, b$. One solution would be $a_1 = a_3 = 1$, $a_2 = 0$ and $b = 0$. Hence, an equation of the plane that passes through the three given points is

$$x_1 + x_3 = 0$$

though any multiple of this equation would also do. Note that this plane also passes through the origin. The vector that is normal to this plane is

$$\mathrm{n} = \begin{bmatrix}1\\ 0 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}$$

We can decompose the point to be projected, $\mathrm{u}$, as the sum of a vector normal to the plane and a vector parallel to the plane

$$\mathrm{u} = \begin{bmatrix}1\\ 1 \\ 1\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}1\\ 0 \\ 1\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} 0\\ 1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix} = \mathrm{n} + \begin{bmatrix} 0\\ 1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$$

Projecting $\mathrm{u}$ onto the plane we obtain only

$$\begin{bmatrix} 0\\ 1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$$

as the projection of a vector normal to the plane onto the same plane is the zero vector.